# Only the last article from XML file visible after successful import into ShopWare 5.4.6

Tags: mysql, xml, shopware

I wanted to distribute over the import function 26 articles in 13 categories. Two in each category.

In Frontend: Unfortunately, in each category I only see the last article (name: bluesea) from my XML file. Also under 'new' and 'Top seller' I only see this article.

In XML file ([official example](https://community.shopware.com/files/DataImportExport/ArticleMinimal.xml)): I have given the articles there all a different order number, a different mainnumber and a different name.
Of course, the category is occasionally the same.

Below the first and the last article of my XML:

```
<Root>
<articles>
    <article>
        <name>greensea</name>
        <ordernumber>1</ordernumber>
        <mainnumber>1</mainnumber>
        <tax>19.00</tax>
        <prices>
            <price>
                <group>EK</group>
                <price>2.99</price>
                <pseudoprice></pseudoprice>
                <baseprice></baseprice>
            </price>
        </prices>
        <active>1</active>
        <description>Isolierpacks..
        </description>
        <category>
            <categories>101</categories>
        </category>
        <description_long>1200g
        </description_long>
    </article>

    <article>
        <name>bluesea</name>
        <ordernumber>26</ordernumber>
        <mainnumber>26</mainnumber>
        <tax>19.00</tax>
        <prices>
            <price>
                <group>EK</group>
                <price>2.99</price>
                <pseudoprice></pseudoprice>
                <baseprice></baseprice>
            </price>
        </prices>
        <active>1</active>
        <description>Bluesea...
        </description>
        <category>
            <categories>103</categories>
        </category>
        <description_long>1 kg</description_long>
    </article>
</articles>
</Root>
```

Previously I installed the shop [shopware 5.4.6](https://github.com/shopware/shopware/releases/tag/v5.4.6), then imported the 13 categories (they are all visible) and created an empty Theme that inherits from the responsive Theme. 
I also have access to the database via phpmyadmin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example should'nt work at all, because it is missing the supplier and this is one of the minimum values that are needed to create a new product. The example from the documentation works fine for me.

[image]

Comment: you are right. i upladet xml with : 
 <ordernumber>SW10123.1</ordernumber>        <mainnumber>SW10123.1</mainnumber>
in every acticle. so it show: 
import works here ([successfully 26](https://i.imgur.com/nTnoqvo.jpg). This above shows: [Supplier not found for article 1.](https://i.imgur.com/qc1YJz5.jpg). For me, the suppliers are currently not important. Main thing the articles are in it. Is there a smple dirty way? For example, add Supplier via phpmyadmin?